# Format a php datetime object to display a date in the future while keeping the date

Tags: php

I am starting with a basic DateTime object and I want to display a date in the future, ex. 5-10 years in the future.

I tried using DateInterval and adding to the initial date, but I want to keep using the initial date and this is where I need help

```
<?php

$initialDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-n-Y', '1-6-2015');

$initialDate->setTime(mt_rand(0,12),mt_rand(0,59),mt_rand(0,59)); // set a random time of day, not really relevant

print $initialDate->format('c') . PHP_EOL;
// 2015-06-01T07:08:22+02:00
print $initialDate->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;
// 2015-06-01

$interval = 'P' . mt_rand(5,11) . 'Y';
$intervalObj = new DateInterval($interval);

$futureDate = $initialDate->add($intervalObj)->format("Y-m-d");
print $futureDate . PHP_EOL;
// 2023-06-01 - this is the expected result

print $initialDate->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;
// 2025-06-01 - i understand why this happens
```

I would like to get the initial date though, which would be `2015-06-01`

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: CAN YOU SHOW WHAT IS EXPECTED OUTCOME?

Comment: just edited the question to make the expected outcome obvious

Comment: `mt_rand(5,11)` not behavive according toyour expectation.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh what do you believe my expectation of `mt_rand` is? and I have to disagree with you because of this `int mt_rand ( int $min , int $max )` and because it's tested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DateTime::add method will actually effect the contents of the object irreversibly. So if you need the original data you will have to make a copy of the object in its state before you use the `->add()` method on it.

You could copy the original date object using `clone` right after you have set it up in the state you want to remember it in. Like so

```
$initialDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-n-Y', '1-6-2015');

$initialDate->setTime(mt_rand(0,12),mt_rand(0,59),mt_rand(0,59)); 

$originalDate = clone $initialDate;
```